# Eclipse project (ACM JAVA) as Android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I made a little project on Eclipse with ACM Java. My question is, how can I 
export it, or use the code I wrote to let it run on an Android system? I know that I can download things like SDK Manager and stuff, but it doesn't work me for really, and it got really frustrating to deal with it, although, I would need to write basically everything from scratch again. Is there an opportunity or do I need to write it in Android Studio to be able to publish it? I could use Unity, but in Unity I can write scripts in Java.

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for quite some time, use Android Studio. But Android programs are very different from plain Java code, you will have to start pretty much from scratch.

Comment: oh okay, thanks. yeah thought so, because of display. i used graphicsprogram in acm and android doesnt have something like this.